# Undefined property errors on one on one relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, one-to-one, eloquent

I have two tables, users and profiles. This table have one on one relationship. I'm trying to access data on profiles by this way:

```
    return view('admin.users.profile')->with('user',User::find(Auth::id()) );
```

and in my blade i'm doing this:

```
<input id="facebook" type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" value="{{ old('facebook', $user->profile()->facebook) }}" required placeholder="Facebook">
```

so what i'm doing wrong here? here's my user Model:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

i got this errors:

```
"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$facebook (View: E:\laragon\www\blog\resources\views\admin\users\profile.blade.php)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Auth::user()
```

return the user. Then find the user id with

```
Auth::user()->id.

return view('admin.users.profile')->with('user',User::find(Auth::user()->id));
```

And in your blade

```
<input id="facebook" type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" value="{{ $user->profile->facebook }}" required placeholder="Facebook">
```

use $user->profile->facebook instead of  $user->profile()->facebook

Comment: Shortcut would be `Auth::id()`.